# Substance painter visible lines appear on mesh

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

I have UV unwrapped my object, and imported it into Substance Painter. I wanted to test to see if the UV unwrapping is correct, so I added a UV grid to it, to see how the mesh is unwrapped, so it seems the quads look proportionally unwrapped. When I import it into Pt I can see Tile on my model, any texture I apply to it, looks like tiles.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to keep UV map continuity ... your UV faces are organised nicely in a grid, but scattered randomly across object surface.
Like here is used **Lightmap Pack** unwrap method (seems to be your case).

In this screen I plugged UVmap node directly to Material Output to let you see how individual faces in UV are randomly placed in UV - zero continuity.

[image]

Try to keep neiborgh faces as much as possible. For Sphere with cube topology you can use default UV map ... if you really need *Lightmap Pack* (or you want it for space efficiency) create an UV map (unwrap) from Cube ...

[image]

Than Subdivide and apply (or if you fave subdivided cube use Cast > Sphere modifier) ...

[image]

Mainly, for the *Lightmap Pac*k alggorhytm is good idea to **set some Margine** ... without that it will (and seems to be your case) generates a lines in between, because of pixel interpolation.

Pixels at edges between two UV faces are contaminated by values of neighbour face placed somewhere else at object surface.

This lines are not visible in color, but especially in Normal or Bump maps (that seems to be your case too).

Comment: Thank you for helpful explanation and example!